# Is the located in information available on any google api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-knowledge-graph

As an example [Google Maps place result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj2LI.png). Features information about whether a location is within a larger complex. The google search result knowledge pane features this same information.

Is this available on a google api that can be queried via third party applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find it, from what I could tell google uses its own geo polygons to work out whether something is inside a location.

So I went with using https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Australia&polygon_geojson=1&format=json to get the location polygons and GeoDjango + Postgis [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PO5Y.png).

Hope this helps someone else out there.